# Error in SQL Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I did this insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `giornale`.`Articolo` 
    (`id_articolo`, `titolo`, `didascalia`, `testo`, `immagine`, 
        `username_r`, `data_art`, `autore`, `id_categoria`, `numero_like`) 
VALUES (NULL, \'titoloooo\', \'ciao ciao\', \'texttttt\', \'immag\', 
           \'admin\', NOW(), \'prova\', \'3\', NULL);
```

and it works fine if I launch it in phpmyadmin sql editor. But if I do it in my php script it returns me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\'titoloooo\', \'ciao ciao\', \'texttttt\', \'immag\',
>   \'admin\', NOW(), \'prova' at line 1

How i can fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you're escaping the quotes that you need to have.

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code? And are you really escaping the single-quotes in your SQL editor? Surely that should fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you have all of those backslashes.

**Remove** them and you should be fine.

```
INSERT INTO `giornale`.`Articolo` 
    (`id_articolo`, `titolo`, `didascalia`, `testo`, `immagine`, 
        `username_r`, `data_art`, `autore`, `id_categoria`, `numero_like`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'titoloooo', 'ciao ciao', 'texttttt', 'immag', 
           'admin', NOW(), 'prova', '3', NULL);
```

Comment: Unless he's using `mysql_query('INSERT INTO...`

Comment: @MichaelRushton well the escaped version should have **failed** in phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that as a comment to his question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape single quotes

```
INSERT INTO `giornale`.`Articolo` 
    (`id_articolo`, `titolo`, `didascalia`, `testo`, `immagine`, 
        `username_r`, `data_art`, `autore`, `id_categoria`, `numero_like`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'titoloooo', 'ciao ciao', 'texttttt', 'immag', 
           'admin', NOW(), 'prova', '3', NULL);
```

Comment: Unless he's using `mysql_query('INSERT INTO...`

Comment: that would be assuming, i'm just working with what was in the question at the time of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes for the string, then you can use single quotes without problems in your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `giornale`.`Articolo` (`id_articolo`, `titolo`, `didascalia`, `testo`, `immagine`, `username_r`, `data_art`, `autore`, `id_categoria`, `numero_like`) VALUES (NULL, 'titoloooo', 'ciao ciao', 'texttttt', 'immag', 'admin', NOW(), 'prova', '3', NULL);";
mysql_query($query); // or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the \' is being brought over to your SQL query. Try removing the escaping and use single quotes alone.

```
INSERT INTO `giornale`.`Articolo` 
    (`id_articolo`, `titolo`, `didascalia`, `testo`, `immagine`, 
        `username_r`, `data_art`, `autore`, `id_categoria`, `numero_like`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'titoloooo', 'ciao ciao', 'texttttt', 'immag', 
           'admin', NOW(), 'prova', '3', NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the whole string were in single quotes `'`, it would work fine.

It looks like you are using double quotes, in which case you don't have to escape the single quotes.